# Get only Some newest Value from database table

Tags: c#, sql-server, versioning

I want to ask something.

Here's the table:

```
A_ID    B_ID    C_ID    Version E_ID    F_ID

1009    2882000 mi7       1      200    01.mi7.LBUS.BSMS5.1360062644 
1009    2882000 mi7       1      200    02.mi7.LBUS.BSMS5.1360062656 
1009    2882000 mi7       1     -130    03.mi7.LBUS.BSMS5.1360062670 
1009    2882000 mi7       2      200    01.mi7.LBUS.BSMS5.1360062681 
1009    2882000 mi7       2      200    02.mi7.LBUS.BSMS5.1360062689
```

I want to get the all value of E_ID and F_ID from table which is newest version refer to version column, the version column will be increase refer to other process and I want always get the newest value

i want the output is :

```
Version    E_ID          F_ID
2        200    01.mi7.LBUS.BSMS5.1360062681 
2        200    02.mi7.LBUS.BSMS5.1360062689
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT E_ID, F_ID
FROM [the table]
WHERE [Version] = (SELECT MAX([Version]) FROM [the table])
```

This will return all rows with Version = 2 in your case.

Comment: @SabilValdano You said "the latest value" as in "value" in the singular, and also didn't provide the sample output which you have now, so I suggested top 1...

Comment: sorry i mean all value from the latest version :)